# How do I do a bulk update in mySQL using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i want to update data in bulk i have over 50 rows to be updated in an array of objects in node JS. something like
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
and [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js/14259347#14259347)

```
var updateData=[ 
    {a: '15',b: 1,c: '24',d: 9,e: 1,f: 0,g: 0,h: 5850,i: 78 },
    {a: '12',b: 1,c: '21',d: 9,e: 1,f: 0,g: 0,h: 55,i: 78 },
    {a: '13',b: 1,c: '34',d: 9,e: 1,f: 0,g: 0,h: 58,i: 78 },
    {a: '14',b: 1,c: '45',d: 9,e: 1,f: 0,g: 0,h: 585,i:78 },
    {a: '16',b: 1,c: '49',d: 9,e: 1,f: 0,g: 0,h: 85,i: 78 } 
]
my query is : update table set a= updateData.a ,b= updateData.b ,c = updateData.c , d==updateData.d ,e=updateData.e,f=updateData.f where e=updateData.e
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating multiple rows with node-mysql, NodeJS and Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552115/updating-multiple-rows-with-node-mysql-nodejs-and-q)

Answer (score 4):

As of I know, there is no direct way to do bulk update records in mySQL. But there is a work around for this - You could execute multiple insert statements and then execute the query to achieve the desired result.

To do this, while creating a connection allow it to execute multiple statements as it is disabled by default.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : dbConfig.host,
          user     : dbConfig.user,
          password : dbConfig.password,
          database : dbConfig.database,
          multipleStatements: true
 });
```

Then, construct the bulk update query in the below syntax by manipulating the inputs you have.

> Query1; Query2; Query3;

Say, for Instance,

```
 update table set a='15', b=1, c='24', d=9, e=1, f=0, g=0, h=5850, i=78;update table set a='12', b=1, c='21', d=9, e=1, f=0, g=0, h=5850, i=78;
```

Then, execute the query as usual,

```
connection.query(sqlQuery, params, callback);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by enabling the multiple statements feature in your mysql connection. Then you can loop through your updateData and construct mysql statements separated by a ';'. You can see an example of this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519758/5215403).

Answer (score 0):

It's really not easy to bulk update data using node-MySQL but here you can do an alternative if you can use .map function in the frontend. Let me show you what i did with mine--

just make a single update API and use it like this in your frontend-

```
 updateData.map((item, key)=>{
    return (
        axios.path('/api/update', {
            a: item.a,
            b: item.b,
            c: item.c
        })
    ).then(()=> console.log('updated'))
    .catch((err)=> console.log(err))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

there are couple ifs, but

- if you have a unique constraint on column `e`
- if you have a default values for all columns in the target table which are not affected by this query

then you can use this slightly nasty way:

```
const sql = `insert into table (a,b,c,d,e,f)
values ?
on duplicate key update
  a = values(a),
  b = values(b),
  c = values(c),
  d = values(d),
  f = values(f)`
```

the use the `query` variant with passed `values` (`updateData` in your case):

```
connection.query(sqlString, updateData, callback)
```

your `updateData` should be an array of arrays of values to go into `a,b,c,d,e,f` columns

Answer (score -1):

A little late answering, but using MySQL JSON_TABLE can help.  Here's a working example:

```
UPDATE person a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        personId, addressType, addressId 
    FROM JSON_TABLE('
        [
            {"personId": 318, "addressType": "Primary", "addressId": 712},
            {"personId": 319, "addressType": "Shipping", "addressId": 712}
        ]',
        '$[*]' COLUMNS(
            personId INT PATH '$.personId',
            addressType VARCHAR(10) path '$.addressType', 
            addressId INT path '$.addressId')
    ) a) b
ON a.personId = b.personId
SET
    a.addressId = b.addressId,
    a.addressType = b.addressType;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).