# Error mysql executing multiple rows with data json

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a multiple rows update.
It works perfectly with 1 row, but with multiple having error sintax.
The configuration hsa been set correctly { ..., multipleStatements: true }

But im doing this kind of query, generated from a mapping of list items.

```
const query = 'UPDATE `ROW_INFO` SET `JSON` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?;UPDATE `ROW_INFO` SET `JSON` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?;'
const values = [ [ {foo:'bar1'}, 1 ], [ {foo:'bar2'}, 2 ] ]
await connection.execute(query, values)
```

I tried all as 1 array, wrapping in array, in 2 arrays, but nothing, having same error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `ROW_INFO` SET `JSON` = `[object Object]` WHERE `ID` = 1' at line 1
```

If i try to set values on string get worst errors, beacuse json can not be set on query for this case.
Hope someone can help me with this kind of error, or how to set the right way the values.

Comment: put the json in quotes, so that iot will not be interpreted as part of the javascript

Comment: i dont understand can u write and example plis? @nbk

Comment: you pass an object to mysql, but you need to pass the json as string, something like andrew already said, mysql will convert the string to json automatcally

Comment: @nbk not only with that, looks like have to change from execute to query too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about running execute for each row separately? (although I'm not sure about the performance)

Like this:

```
const values = [ [ {foo:'bar1'}, 1 ], [ {foo:'bar2'}, 2 ] ]

for (const value of values){
    await connection.execute(query, value)
}
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs) thread for other examples.

Comment: thats the problem, the performance, im trying to minimize this, also a for with await is wrong option, should be like a promise all, but it creates n times connections for execute, so is like execevie if you have to update 100 rows for example

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña yeah, you are right. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415464/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-update-in-mysql-using-node-js) is another thread on the topic. A (straighforward) workaround would be to add parameters to a query for each element in `values` array inside `for` cycle and add  this query to the final query on which to call `connection.execute()` (in the end, after the `for` cycle)