# How to update multiple rows in mysql using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am facing problem while updating multiple rows in table.
following is my data

```
const update_Data = upins_data.map(
                upins_data => [{
                    upin_id: upins_data.upin_id,
                    media_type: upins_data.media_type,
                    land: upins_data.land
                }]
            );
```

it has multiple values.
i have tired following code

```
var updateSecTab = `UPDATE tb_bid_upins SET upin_id=?,media_type=?,land=? WHERE bid_id = ?`;
            var query = db.query(updateSecTab,[update_Data,cond],function(error,result,fields){

                if (error) { /**If error while inserting into table 2 it rowback the Transaction */
                    console.log('in err 1');
                    return db.rollback(function () {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
                db.commit(function (err, result3) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('in err 2');
                        return db.rollback(function () {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }
                    /**Send success result to front end */
                    console.log('success!');
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
                })
            });
            console.log(query.sql);
```

When i print the query it gives result as follows

```
UPDATE tb_bid_upins SET upin_id=('[object Object]'), ('[object Object]'),media_type=1,land=? WHERE bid_id = ?
```

Comment: Can you show the `update_Data` and `cond` objects?

Comment: @Molda this is my update data object
    `[ [ { upin_id: 1, media_type: 5, land: 'Rakhiyal Circle' } ],
    [ { upin_id: 3, media_type: 6, land: 'Rakhiyal Circle' } ] ]`
and this is cond **bid_id=1**

Comment: I don't think you can do multiple updates this way. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519758/3284355

Comment: @Molda I have already seen this answer.is that right way??

Comment: I don't know. You can also try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866431/3284355 which might be better since it is only single query.

Comment: @Molda thank you for your response.But this two solution are not working for me.Do you have any other solution, i am stuck on this task from 3 days and i dont have much exp in **node.js**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195735/discussion-between-sang-and-molda).

Comment: Did anyone find any efficient solution to this?

Comment: @IbrahimFarooq check answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello everyone i have tried following solution and it works.

```
var upins_data = [ { upin_id: 1, media_type: 5, land: 'Rakhiyal Circle' } ],
[ { upin_id: 3, media_type: 6, land: 'Rakhiyal Circle' } ]
var cond = 1
```

i have added above two variable in single array as follows

```
const update_Data = upins_data.map(
      upins_data => {
        return {
          bid_id: cond,
          upin_id: upins_data.upin_id,
          media_type: upins_data.media_type,
          land: upins_data.land
        }
      }
    );
```

than i have used foreach on update_Data array and i have created multiple sql quires using mysql foramt function.

```
var queries = '';
update_Data.forEach(function (item) {
      let sql = mysql.format("UPDATE tb_bid_upins SET upin_id=?,media_type=?,land=? WHERE bid_id = ? ;", [item.upin_id,item.media_type, item.land, item.bid_id]);
      queries += sql;
      console.log(sql);
    });
```

than i have passed above queries variable in sql query as follows

```
db.query(queries,(err,result)=>{
   if(err){
      console.log('err',err);
    }else{
      console.log('result',result);
    }    
  });
```

above code works for me in **nodejs** .

if anyone wants to improve than they can.
thank you